# What do "Mouse Button 6 – 16" correspond to in Logitech's configuration software?

Tags: windows, mouse, mission-control

The Mission Control Preference Pane allows me to assign actions to one of 15 mouse buttons.

[image]

My Logitech G305 only has six buttons, but I can re-assign each one in Logitech's configuration software (saved to the mouse's on-board memory). I run this ugly software in a Windows VM so it doesn't touch my beautiful OS X installation.

[image: Ugly Logitech Software]

Although Logitech's software only explicitly lists Mouse Buttons 1–3 as options, I know from experience that "Back" corresponds to "Mouse Button 4" in OS X, and "Forward" corresponds to "Mouse Button 5". I have assigned these functions and confirmed they work in Mission Control.

Does anyone happen to know what any of the other functions correspond to? I only have one button left, so I only need to find *one* more Logitech-Apple pair.

I *could* of course manually try each one, and I may do that, if I get desperate enough. However, as this would take an exceedingly long time (switching the USB device between the VM and my Mac is cumbersome), I'm hoping there's some sort of standard being followed. What would a "Mouse Button 6" *normally* do on a Windows PC?

Most people on the internet recommend assigning keyboard macros, but I'd like to avoid that as it feels like more of a hack. OS X has native support for mouse buttons; I want to use it.

Comment: I think the Logitech software swallows all those mouse events up and you can only use its mappings. When I used a different Logitech mouse I removed all Logitech software and got the native mouse buttons

Comment: @mmmmmm As I noted in the question, I don't actually have the Logitech software installed on my Mac, it's isolated in a Windows VM. I'm just using the software to set the buttons, which is saved to the mouse hardware itself.

Comment: Just to be clear, I can set clicking the scroll wheel to "Back" in the software, and OS X will see a scroll wheel click as "Mouse Button 4" instead of "Mouse Button 3", without any software installed (outside of the isolated VM), until I change it back.

Comment: Possibly none of the above? Willing to bet that for things like scroll left/scroll right it basically emulates the corresponding HID wheel events and for next track it sends keyboard events. See what happens if you don't map the buttons at all? Will it fall back to the default/generic hid profile? You can capture and log cgevent with "all" mask to find out.

Comment: @1110101001 It's a good thought, but there's no option to unassign a button. They come mapped to functions out of the box, which you can replace but not delete. (Which may well mean that what I want is just impossible.)

Comment: @Wowfunhappy Seems like people have reverse engineered the logitech protocol and creates libraries to do arbitrary remapping. Can you connect the mouse to a linux box and try using libratbag to see if you can rebind to the standard mouse button 1..5? (Hard mode would be to try to port libratbag to osx, but that seems like overkill since it's easier to set the buttons once and do any button->action translation higher up in the stack).

Comment: @1110101001 Ha, perfect! I hadn't found libratbag, thank you! (I was using a Windows VM anyway, it's very easy to spin up a Linux one!)

Comment: On the G305 isn't button 6 the DPI button?

Comment: @TimD By default, yes, but that can be changed in the software. I always keep my mouse set to one DPI.

Comment: @Wowfunhappy it seems the G305 doesn't support a Mouse Button 6 in the same sense as Mouse Button 4 and 5. What you may wish to do though is use G HUB or LGS on a Windows VM and configure the buttons as keystrokes and set it to Onboard Memory mode which saves the keystroke macro to the G305 internal memory allow the mouse to be shared across devices without any third-party software. I've done this for a G300S and a G305 which I have currently.